# Ajax action only on specific class

Tags: javascript, ajax, class

I have different tables on a webpage, but would like to trigger Ajax (in this case, updating the columns of a table) only on a particular table.

Actually, learning the way to apply the action to 'everything but class X' would be just as nice as to find out how to apply the action 'only to class X'.

Example code:

```
<table class="currtable1">
<thead>
<td colspan="5">
Table 1
<SELECT name="menu">
        <option value="eur">EUR</option>
        <option value="thb">THB</option>
        <option value="btc">BTC</option>
        <option value="eth">ETH</option>
        <option value="xmr">XMR</option>
        </SELECT>
</td> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>column EUR</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column THB</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column BTC</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column ETH</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column XMR</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>column EUR</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column THB</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column BTC</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column ETH</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column XMR</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<table class="currtable2">
<thead>
<td colspan="5">
Table 2
</td> 
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>column EUR</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column THB</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column BTC</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column ETH</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column XMR</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>column EUR</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column THB</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column BTC</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column ETH</td>
       <td style="display:none;">column XMR</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript (I try to update only "currtable2" when the selection changes, but it doesn't work that way):

```
$(document).on('change', "table.currtable2 thead select", function() {

  var index = $('option:selected',this).index()+1;

  console.log(index)
  $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find("td").hide();
       $(this).find("td:nth-child("+index+")").show();
  });

});
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jsrookey/z8pj7dns/2/

Comment: what problem you are facing ? fiddle is different than above code ...

Comment: sorry for the confusion … I forgot to create another version for my tests after posting this. Meanwhile I have figured it out, answer below. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Change select by adding class

for example:

```
<SELECT name="menu" class="menu">
        <option value="eur">EUR</option>
        <option value="thb">THB</option>
        <option value="btc">BTC</option>
        <option value="eth">ETH</option>
        <option value="xmr">XMR</option>
        </SELECT>
</td>
```

in javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".menu").change(function(){
            // your logic here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to only update one of both tables:

```
$(document).on('change', 'table thead select', function() {

  var index = $('option:selected',this).index()+1;

  $('table.currtable1 tbody tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find("td").hide();
      $(this).find("td:nth-child("+index+")").show();
  });
});
```